# Is it possible to create a `TYPE ... TABLE` that uses the columns of an existing table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with SQL Server, and have a table and type like below ...

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
  Id BIGINT,
  Age INT,
  DateCreated DATETIME2
);

CREATE TYPE FooRow AS TABLE (
  Id BIGINT,
  Age INT,
  DateCreated DATETIME2
);
```

I use the `FooRow` type in a stored procedure, as the return type, in which I query some records from `Foo` table, store them in a `FooRow` variable, do some other things with them, and finally output the `FooRow` variable.

Is there a way to reduce this repeated typing of the `Foo` table schema to create the `FooRow` type?

Is it possible to express a stored procedure variable's type as an existing table, or something?

```
DECLARE @foorows TABLE Foo
```

If not, is it possible to create a type, like `FooRow`, and just say "use the columns from `Foo`"?

Comment: Would a [`select ... into ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement meet your needs?

Comment: @HABO: no, a SELECT INTO will create a table, not a type.

Comment: @RazvanSocol True, `select ... into ...` creates a table, not a type. It is, however, applicable to selecting some data from a table for subsequent manipulation and return from a stored procedure without prior knowledge of the complete table schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare table variables to have a certain table type, but this type has to be created with a CREATE TYPE statement (it cannot be another existing table). However, you can script the definition of an existing table (using SSMS) and change only the first line manually.

You can also define a table-valued function to return a certain table type. The advantage of a table-valued function (over a stored procedure) is that they may be called from a query (or even from a view). Although there are additional restrictions of what a table-valued function can do (mainly, it cannot modify any data that resides outside the function), you should consider using them instead of nested stored procedures (in other words, when the result of the stored procedure must be processed further in another procedure).